# Searching a 2D nested list based on index value

Tags: python, list

I want to search for a string in 2d nested list and get the next value in the same nested list.

```
list_1=[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["a", "e"],["c", "f"]]
search="c"
```

Example: If I am searching for "c" then I should get element "d" and "f" and suppose if I am searching for "a" ,it should return "b" and "e".

Here is what I have tried. I am able to return index of next element as required which is again in form of nested list but I am unable to fetch element itself. Please provide some suggestions.

```
out = [[elem,elen+1] for elem,i in enumerate(list_1) for elen,y in enumerate(i) if search in y]
#[[1, 1], [3, 1]]
```

**Note**: No hardcoding and it ain't a duplicate. If order is maintained it would be more good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below

```
list_1=[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["a", "e"],["c", "f"]]
search="c"
list_2 = [e[1] for e in list_1 if search == e[0]]
print(list_2)
```

output

```
['d', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

list_1=np.array([["a", "b"],
       ["c", "d"],
       ["a", "e"],
       ["c", "f"]])
list_result = list_1[list_1[:,0]=="c"]
print(list_result[:, 1])
```